# How to get major:minor for a platform_driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

i've wrote a platform_driver for Linux.
Now, i want it to be a char device under /dev/myDrv.

Right now, the driver doesn't appear in /dev/myDrv although I successfully load it with 'insmod'.

I guess, i have to create a char device with 'mknod /dev/myDrv c *MAJOR* *MINOR*'. Correct?

Well, the problem is i don't know how to find major:minor for my driver.

After 'insmod myDrv' there are some files generated under:

- /sys/bus/platform/devices/myDrv
- /sys/devices/platform/myDrv
- /sys/module/myDrv

Do they help me in any way.

Or how to find major:minor for a platform_driver?

Comment: http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.in/2015/08/linux-kernel-module-programming.html

Answer (score 0):

When developing a driver you have to do two basic steps before anything else: register for `<major,minor>`  range and then link the device file operations to the device driver functions.

Following is the working code for the `init` and `exit` modules of a basic char driver:

```
static int __init char_init(void)
{
        int ret;
        struct device *dev_ret;

        printk(KERN_INFO "Char device registered");
        if ((ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&first, 0, 3, "Abhinav")) < 0)
                {
                        return ret;
                }
        if (IS_ERR(cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "char_dev")))
        {
                unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
                return PTR_ERR(cl);
        }
        if (IS_ERR(dev_ret = device_create(cl, NULL, first, NULL, "mynull")))
        {
                class_destroy(cl);
                unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
                return PTR_ERR(dev_ret);
        }

        cdev_init(&c_dev, &file_ops);
        if ((ret = cdev_add(&c_dev, first, 1)) < 0)
        {
                device_destroy(cl, first);
                class_destroy(cl);
                unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
                return ret;
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "<Major,Minor>: <%d, %d>\n", MAJOR(first), MINOR(first));
        return 0;
}

static void __exit char_exit(void)
{
        cdev_del(&c_dev);
        device_destroy(cl, first);
        class_destroy(cl);
        unregister_chrdev_region(first, 3);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye: Char device unregistered");
}
```

The `probe` and `disconnect` are left up to you.

In this code, the call to `alloc_chrdev_region` is done to register for the major and minor numbers.

And the `class_create` and `device_create` API's are used for the creation of device file `mynull`.

After executing, `/dev/mynull` will be created.